# Как сделать единоразовый поллинг Python Telebot

Tags: python, telebot

Я делаю бота на python telebot, и хочу сделать будильник. Я уже сделал запись будильников, но чтобы каждый тик проверять, наступил ли нужный час и минута, мне нужно запихнуть в цикл типа

```
...
while 1:
    bot.poll()
    if minute == current_minute and... :
        bot.send_message(id, message)
...
```

id чата, проверку, сейчас ли нужный момент и сообщение я уже сделал, но bot.poll() команды нет, а bot.polling() вечно работает. Как сделать, чтобы в одном цикле происходил один тик проверки сообщений ботом? Или какие другие варианты есть, чтобы выполнялась та же функция

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил это, сделав отдельный файл с тем же токеном бота, в котором это проверял.

Comment: А как выглядит другой файл с ботом? т.е. что поменялось в нем. И нет ли конфликта при одновременно работающих ботах с одним и тем же токеном?

Comment: Я просто создал ещё один файл, назвал bot_alarm.py. В нём по стандарту import telebot, написал bot = telebot.TeleBot(токен), но ни хендлеров, ни bot.polling(). Потом просто написал цикл while 1:, в котором всё проверял, а когда проверка проходила, то bot.send_message